# Python function not returning values

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

I'm creating a digital clock timer with two timers. The first is 30 mins and second is 30 to 20 secs depending on how long is left in the first timer. To reset the second clock every 30 or 20 seconds i created a function to call it to set the shottimer back to 30. However it is not returning the value of the shot timer any ideas why. Code is below

```
def countdown(matchtime,shottime):
    matchstr = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=matchtime))
    shottimestr = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=shottime))
    lbl_text['text'] = matchstr
    lbl_textshot['text'] = shottimestr
    if shottime == 0:

        ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)
        print (shottime)
    if matchtime > 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, matchtime-1, shottime-1)    
        print (shottime)    
        matchstr = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=matchtime))
        shottimestr = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=shottime))

        lbl_text['text'] = matchstr
        lbl_textshot['text'] = shottimestr


    elif(matchtime == 0):
        global NewForm
        NewForm = Toplevel() 
        NewForm.title("Sourcecodester")
        width = 500
        height = 300
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
        y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
        NewForm.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
        NewForm.resizable(0, 0)
        lbl_blast = Label(NewForm, text="Blast Off!", font=('arial', 50))
        lbl_blast.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=100)
        btn_back = Button(NewForm, text="Reset", font=('arial', 16), command=BackBtn)
        btn_back.pack(side=TOP)
```

```
def ShotTime(matchtime, shottime):
        if shottime == 0 and matchtime > 900:
            shottime = 30
            return matchtime, shottime
        elif matchtime <= 900 and shottime == 0:
            shottime = 20
            return matchtime, shottime
```

Comment: What if the `condition` don't match both the cases ?. So try putting the `return` out side the `if..else`

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's impossible to tell where the error is when the second line crashes the interpreter :)

Comment: Is the indentation a formating error on when you posted your code, or is it like this in your code. I assuming it is just in SO, otherwise you would get an error. Would you be able to fix it?

Comment: This code won't run as is. In addition to indentation issues with the first function, there are several undefined terms like `Toplevel`. Please create an example that can be run exactly as written and show both the actual output and what you expected.

Comment: The indetion in the python file is find it messes up when i put in the post

Comment: @LukeMayor fix it.

Comment: Fix the indentation on the post

Comment: Are `lbl_text` and `lbl_textshot` supposed to be dictionnaries? If so they are not defined anywhere. Can you also add the imported libraries

Comment: @LukeMayor there's no need to add an edit detailing your results. If an answer solved the problem for you (like Aurum's seems to have), you should consider clicking the green checkmark next to that answer to Accept it. This gives both you and the answerer some reputation and lets future readers see which answer was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)** takes its parameters by value not by reference. Setting

```
shottime = 30
```

Will only affect the value you return. You're not using that value. e.g.

```
ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)
```

You may wish to change to

```
matchtime, shottime = ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a return statement in def ShotTime but you don't have ShotTime equal to anything.

Edit:
To elaborate more you have 
`def ShotTime(matchtime, shottime):

```
if shottime == 0 and matchtime > 900:
    shottime = 30
    return matchtime, shottime
elif matchtime <= 900 and shottime == 0:
    shottime = 20
    return matchtime, shottime`
```

So you have return statements there.

```
if shottime == 0:

ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)
print (shottime)
```

but in def countdown() you dont have it being set equal to anything. I believe in python you have to do something like x = ShotTime(matchtime,shottime) and that will return a array, then do like matchtime = x[0] then shottime = x[1]

edit2: this is a better way thx @kevin   matchtime, shottime = ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)

This has to do with variable scope. Unless it is a global variable, variables stay in the function they are created. Just because it has the same name does not mean it is the same variable.

Comment: huh? I'm not sure what that means

Comment: ShotTime is the function shottime,matchtime are the value that should be return

Comment: I interpret this to mean "returning a value from ShotTime isn't useful unless you assign the result to something. Replace `ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)` in `countdown` with `matchtime, shottime = ShotTime(matchtime, shottime)`"

Comment: Thanks u this works im not too fimlair with python i though when i return shottime and matchtime from def Shottime it would automatically change the values as it uses them values. thanks again